# Active Record Find By Column 'OR' Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to perform a find_by query using an 'or' statement? For example:

```
@product ||= Product.find_by_upc(params[:code]) if params[:code]
@product ||= Product.find_by_cspc(params[:code]) if params[:code]
```

As something like (does not work):

```
@product ||= Product.find_by_upc_or_cspc(params[:code]) if params[:code]
```

Thanks!

Comment: How would you take one of these answers and create a `Product.find_by_code`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Rails 6, ActiveRecord has an [`or`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) operator.

It doesn't work exactly how you'd expect, as you need to create a brand new query inside the `or`. But it's nice to avoid needing raw SQL.

```rb
Person.where(first_name: "John").or(Person.where(last_name: "Smith"))
```

This generates the following SQL under the hood.

```sql
SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE ("people"."first_name" = $1 OR "people"."last_name" = $2) LIMIT $3
[["first_name", "John"], ["last_name", "Smith"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

Answer (score 22):

As of Rails 5, one way to do this is as follows:

For the first matching record:

```
Product.find_by("upc = ? OR cspc = ?", params[:code], params[:code])
```

For all matching records:

```
Product.where("upc = ? OR cspc = ?", params[:code], params[:code])
```

Answer (score 9):

Not using Activerecord methods

This might work:

```
code = params[:code]
@product = Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["upc = ? or cspc = ?", code, code])
```

Answer (score 6):

Cleaning up nicholas' code:

```
@products = Product.all(:conditions => ["upc = :code or cspc = :code", {:code => params[:code]}])
```

Comment: Thanks Omar for the nice refractor. I ended up doing this to clean up the code a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Arel](http://github.com/rails/arel) on Rails 3:

```
t = Product.arel_table

@products = Product.where(
  t[:upc].eq(params[:code])       \
  .or(t[:cspc].eq(params[:code]))
)

@product = @products.first if @products.size == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Rails doesn't support automatic OR finders, out of the box. But the `searchlogic` gem appears to support this feature. See [here](http://www.binarylogic.com/2009/08/26/using-searchlogic-to-combine-named-scopes-with-or/)

Comment: Yeah, that was what I thought. I took a look at the search-logic gem and have used it in the past. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem like this before.

One way to approach it is to try and figure out what type of data you're getting in the first place. Write some code that will tell you the difference.

Maybe see if there is a regex way to distinguish between UPC and CSPC.

Comment: Good point. I could take a look at adding a length check (the UPC-A codes are all 12 characters, and CSPC are 6 or 7 I believe). Thanks.